# Dismissing UINavigationController opened via Plaid SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, react-native-ios, plaid

I have hit a road block with integrating the Plaid SDK into our existing React Native application.

We have some older code within our AppDelegate that wraps root within a `UINavigationController`. This is causing an issue when we invoke the Plaid SDK as you are not able to correctly close the Plaid interface.

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to close the entire view via the Plaid close button when using `UINavigationController`.

I apologise if this is obvious, I'm still learning the native iOS and Android stacks and have spent a while looking for a solution without success.

This is a snippet of our `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method side `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"plaidRNDemo"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];
  
  self.reactViewController = [UIViewController new];
  self.reactViewController.view = rootView;
  UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.reactViewController];
  navigationController.delegate = self;
  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    self.window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleLight;
    navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
  }
  
  self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;
}
```

Tapping the close button here does not close the screen as expected and instead ends up in the state on right in the screenshot below with a blank screen (presumably an empty view).

Error state:

[image]

The following is the same snippet from `AppDelegate.m` in which we do not use `UINavigationController` to create the the view which works just fine, tapping the close button correct closes the entire view:

```
{
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"plaidRNDemo"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

Tapping the close button here successfully closes the entire view and results in the state on right in the screenshot below. Unfortunately, I do need to get this working with the existing implementation. I am hoping there is an easy way to trigger a close of the entire view when the close button within the SDK is tapped.

Success state:

[image]

If anyone could provide any help here I would be extremely grateful

Javascipt code that triggers the SDK looks like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { PlaidLink, LinkSuccess, LinkExit } from "react-native-plaid-link-sdk";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import {
  LoadingContainer,
  Button,
} from "sharedComponents";
import {
  getPlaidLinkToken,
  handlePlaidExit,
} from "app/orders/bankAccount/bankAccountActions";
import { getBankAccountLinkingToken } from "app/orders/bankAccount/bankAccountSelectors";

const AddBankAccountContainer = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const linkingToken: string = useSelector(getBankAccountLinkingToken) ?? "";
  const onSuccess = (success: LinkSuccess) =>
  dispatch(handlePlaidSuccess(success));
const onExit = (exit: LinkExit) => dispatch(handlePlaidExit(exit));

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPlaidLinkToken());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <LoadingContainer>
      ...
      <View style={[s.mt4, s.flx_i, s.jcfe, s.mb5]}>
        <PlaidLink
          tokenConfig={{
            token: linkingToken,
          }}
          onSuccess={onSuccess}
          onExit={onExit}
        >
          <Button I18nId={"bankAccount.addBank.cta"} />
        </PlaidLink>
      </View>
    </LoadingContainer>
  );
};

export default AddBankAccountContainer;
```

This component is navigated to via react-navigation:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";

const bottomTabScreens = {
  profileTab: {
    path: "profile",
    screen: createStackNavigator(
      ...
      {
        addBankAccount: {
          path: "bankAccount/add",
          screen: AddBankAccountContainer,
        },
      },
   },
}

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(scenes, {
  mode: "modal",
  defaultNavigationOptions: () => ({
    animationEnabled: !isTest,
    cardStyleInterpolator: forFade,
    transitionSpec: modalTransitionSpec,
    headerShown: false,
  }),
});

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your `MainNavigator`, navigate to the page you want the user to see after Link has exited. This can be done by adding `navigation.pop();` to the `onSuccess` and `onExit` handlers in your `AddBankAccountContainer`

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I am actually doing this else where in the `handlePlaidSuccess` and `handlePlaidExit` actions but it does not solve the issue of actually closing the UINavigationController view.

I'll create an issue with a simple reproducible version of this under the react-native-plaid-link-sdk repo based on the same code in this repos example folder.

Thanks!